# FindItem(R.id.*) throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, menu, menuitem

I would like to add `onMenuItemClickListener` for my menu entries. The problem is that when I try to access `menu.findItem(R.id.*)` outside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, I always get `NullPointerException`. For some reason, menu items are still unavaliable for any other functions, I have no idea, why...

```
    public Menu items_type;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items_type, menu);
        items_type=menu;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        items_type.clear();
        MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener common = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if(items_type.findItem(R.id.filename).isChecked() && menuItem.getItemId()==R.id.tracktitle)
                {
                    items_type.findItem(R.id.tracktitle).setChecked(true);
                    items_type.findItem(R.id.filename).setChecked(false);
                }
                else if(items_type.findItem(R.id.tracktitle).isChecked() && menuItem.getItemId()==R.id.filename)
                {
                    items_type.findItem(R.id.filename).setChecked(true);
                    items_type.findItem(R.id.tracktitle).setChecked(false);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        items_type.findItem(R.id.tracktitle).setOnMenuItemClickListener(common);
        items_type.findItem(R.id.filename).setOnMenuItemClickListener(common);
        return true;
    }

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}

/res/menu/items_type.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@id/group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
    android:id="@id/filename"
android:title=" File Names"
app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
android:id="@id/tracktitle"
android:title="ID3 Titles"
app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </group>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to handle the menu clickevent like this
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items_type, menu);
    }

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int i = item.getItemId();
    if (i == android.R.id.home) {
    } else if (i == R.id.action_share_pdf) {
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: But how to access other menu items (except selected) from onOptionsItemSelected?

Comment: i executed your code, can i know why you are using items_type.clear(); in onPrepareOptionsMenu this caused me the null pointer exception.. when i removed it it is working

Comment: onOptionsSelected is only for selected items.